# named pipes provider, error: 40 c#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

I keep getting this error when I try to get a result from a query as a list. I can connect to the database if I try to get 1 result.

The code is:

```
string connectionString = "server=ip;uid=root;pwd=pass;database=database;";
string queryString = "SELECT pass_name FROM passStore";

List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    tempList.Add(reader[0].ToString() + " " + reader[1].ToString());
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Post the full exception message and its stack trace.

Comment: Check your reader[0] and reader[1] DBNull before use .ToString

Comment: I added the exception message to the post

Comment: That means your db connection is failed

Comment: Also, the error occurs when the connection is opened

Comment: But earlier on in the program I can connect fine when I try to get only 1 result from the query

Comment: If you're having intermittent connection issues then it's likely that we can't help. I was going to suggest enabling named pipes, but if it's working earlier then I'm not sure.

Comment: The server could be down or the server stop working.

Comment: its not down because if i restart the program this is the only part where it cant connect. It is fine everyother time

Comment: If you're using MySql (as per your tags) then you need to use a `MySqlConnection` not a `SqlConnection` (and `MySqlCommand` etc)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with phpMyAdmin, which is a graphical tool for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database installation. Perhaps that tag got applied by mistake.